Safari Browser is not using Cache Memory for Videos, rather it fetches the same video again
I'm using react player to render videos in my application. Whenever I provide the URL to the player it fetches the video and plays it in the player. But when the same URL is fetched it used from cache memory and not requested again. This is working fine in chrome. But in Safari it fetches the video (even if it is the previously played video URL) and not use cache memory for that.
Does anyone has a solution for that?
I tried to load the videos in Safari from cache but it didn't worked out and I want to load the videos from cache.
